# k8s Keycloak not persistent

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I have a problem with my Keycloak deployed on k8s, every time a new pods is spawned or recreated pod, Keycloak data is lost, how can I make Keycloak persistent? This is my setup:

Manifest:

```
---
apiVersion: "apps/v1"
kind: "Deployment"
metadata:
  name: kc-dp
  labels:
    app: kc
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kc
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kc-container
          image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21.1.1
          args: ["start-dev"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: kc-env
            - secretRef:
                name: kc-secret
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/startup/elements
              name: kc-ps
      volumes:
        - name: kc-ps
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: keycloak-pv-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: keycloak
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30000
```

Persistent Volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: kc-pv
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Persistent Volume Claim:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: kc-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Config map:

```
DB_DATABASE=kc_db
```

Secret map

```
DB_VENDOR=MYSQL
DB_ADDR=mysql-svc
DB_USER=foo
DB_PASSWORD=fooo
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
KEYCLOAK_LOGLEVEL=ALL
KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=pwd
```

How could I solve the problem? Also it seems that Keycloak doesn't save anything on my mysql DB.

Comment: The `hostPath` volume isn't tied to a specific node.  If your Pod gets deleted and recreated on a different node, it will try using that same directory on the new node and find it empty.  Can you let the cluster create the PersistentVolume, rather than creating it yourself?  (Also consider using a StatefulSet and not a Deployment for this scenario.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simpler than it seemed, following the keyclock guide and setting the appropriate environment variables I managed to persist my keyclock.

https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-kube

https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config

thank you, all.